# Iterate through a String Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, swift-playground, swift2, xcode7

I am trying to do a very simple piece of code in Swift playgrounds.

```
var word = "Zebra"

for i in word {
  print(i)
}
```

However, I always get an error on line 3.

> 'String' does not have a member named 'Generator'

Any ideas on why this doesn't work? Note: I am working in Xcode 7, with Swift 2.0 ([Strings and Characters).](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

As of Swift 2, `String` doesn't conform to `SequenceType`. However, you can use the `characters` property on `String`. `characters` returns a [`String.CharacterView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_String-CharacterView_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structctr/String.CharacterView/s:FVSS13CharacterViewcFMS_FSSS_) which conforms to `SequenceType` and so can be iterated through with a `for` loop:

```
let word = "Zebra"

for i in word.characters {
    print(i)
}
```

Alternatively, you could add an extension to `String` to make it conform to `SequenceType`:

```
extension String: SequenceType {}

// Now you can use String in for loop again.
for i in "Zebra" {
    print(i)
}
```

Although, I'm sure Apple had a reason for removing `String`'s conformance to `SequenceType` and so the first option seems like the better choice. It's interesting to explore what's possible though.

Comment: the reason why String doesn't conform to SequenceType is that the same String can be represented by more than one sequence of elements.

Answer (score 9):

`String` doesn't conform to `SequenceType` anymore. However you can access the `characters` property of it this way:

```
var word = "Zebra"

for i in word.characters {
    print(i)
}
```

Note that the documentation hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: Thanks this helped me when I couldn't figure out how to use `reverse` on a String. It must be `for char in string.characters.reverse() {...}`

Answer (score 3):

## Swift 4

***Forin*** loop:

```
let word = "Swift 4"
for i in word {
    print(i)
}
```

***map*** example:

```
let word = "Swift 4"
_ = word.map({ print($0) })
```

***forEach*** example:

```
let word = "Swift 4"
word.forEach({ print($0) })
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3.0.1**

Use the `indices` property of the `characters` property to access all of the `indices` of individual characters in a string.

```
let greeting = "Guten Tag!"
for index in greeting.characters.indices {
print("\(greeting[index]) ", terminator: "")
}
// Prints "G u t e n   T a g ! "
```

visit https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html