# 'String' does not conform to protocol 'CollectionType' Error in Swift 2.0

Tags: error-handling, swift2, xcode7

I just downloaded XCode Beta 7 and received the error "Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'CollectionType'". This is my first attempt at coding, so I'm not sure how to fix this. Thank you!!!

```
//the Pasteboard is nil if full access is not granted
            let pbWrapped: UIPasteboard? = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
            if let pb = pbWrapped {
                var type = UIPasteboardTypeListImage[0] as! String
                if (count(type) > 0) && (image != nil) {
                    pb.setData(UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)!, forPasteboardType: type)
                    var readDataWrapped: NSData? = pb.dataForPasteboardType(type)
                    if let readData = readDataWrapped {
                        var readImage = UIImage(data: readData, scale: 2)
                        print("\(image) == \(pb.image) == \(readImage)")
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Comment: @PhillipMills  if (count(type) > 0) && (image != nil) {

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037711/get-the-length-of-a-string  Especially the note about Swift 2 changes in the accepted answer.

Comment: @PhillipMills, Thank you! However, I'm still a bit confused on how to implement this (I'm a noob to coding apps, I only started learning a couple days ago).

Comment: Going by that answer -- I haven't tried it -- the suggestion would be: `if (type.characters.count > 0) && (image != nil) {`.

Comment: Just replace _count(type)_ with _!type.isEmpty_ and that's it.

Comment: And what's your goal? Get _UIImage_ from pasteboard? You're setting it, getting it, ... Describe with words what your goal is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterate through a String Swift 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30767594/iterate-through-a-string-swift-2-0)

Comment: Thank you, @PhillipMills, this solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
type.characters.count
```

Your code should then read:

```
//the Pasteboard is nil if full access is not granted
        let pbWrapped: UIPasteboard? = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
        if let pb = pbWrapped {
            var type = UIPasteboardTypeListImage[0] as! String
            if (type.characters.count > 0) && (image != nil) {
                pb.setData(UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)!, forPasteboardType: type)
                var readDataWrapped: NSData? = pb.dataForPasteboardType(type)
                if let readData = readDataWrapped {
                    var readImage = UIImage(data: readData, scale: 2)
                    print("\(image) == \(pb.image) == \(readImage)")
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion for where to start learning about this issue... https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=30
    Strings in Swift 2