# Swift how to iterate symbols from string

Tags: swift

I am trying to get array of strings form string. It's separate symbols that I want to iterate.

```
 let chars = binaryString.characters.map { String($0) }

    for (index, item) in chars {

      let activeDay = (index, item)

      switch activeDay {
      case (Days.Monday.rawValue, "1"):
        mondayLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
      case (Days.Monday.rawValue, "0"):
        mondayLabel.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
```

But Xcode says `Expression type '[String]' is ambiguous without more context`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through a String Swift 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30767594/iterate-through-a-string-swift-2-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use all benefits of Swift:

```
var binaryString = "12312312312312312"

let characters = Array(binaryString.characters)

//Values
for char in characters {
    print(char)
}

//Keys and values
for (index, item) in characters.enumerate() {
    print(index)
    print(item)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your code to work, you need to add `enumerate()` to the `chars` array:

```
for (index, item) in chars.enumerate() {
    ...
```

The resulting `chars` array is of `[String]` type, and trying to enumerate it as an index-object tuple produces an error.